# Run only one build per node on Jenkins, multiple pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Currently have multiple pipelines (A, B, C) on Jenkins with nodes (X, Y, Z). We enabled the Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin to make sure only one build from a pipeline is run on a single node.

The problem is, with this approach, builds from different pipelines can collide (for example, pipeline A could already be executing on node X, and we don't want any other pipelines executing on node X until pipeline A is done). The TCB plugin makes sure that multiple builds from a single pipeline doesn't run on one node, but it doesn't prevent multiple pipelines spawning one build on a single node.

How do I configure Jenkins so that nodes can only run one build, NOT per pipeline?

Comment: Configure only one executor per node so that only one build can execute at any point of time and any others triggered wait until the current job completes execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the Node to have just 1 executor. You can achieve this from:

> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> Select the node you want to restrict
>   -> Set 'No of Executors to 1' -> Save.